# Kubernetes Security: How to check the token of service account?

Tags: kubernetes

#### First, I have created a service account `jenkins`

```
> kubectl create serviceaccount jenkins
serviceaccount/jenkins created
```

#### Second, create a token for this service account.

```
> kubectl create token jenkins
eyJhbGc****************iQS-AVXfIzA
```

#### Then, I run `kubectl describe serviceaccount jenkins` command to check the tokens of newly created service account.

But the output shows None tokens.

```
> kubectl describe serviceaccount jenkins

Name:                jenkins
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>  
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>   <===== look at this!
Events:              <none>
```

#### Questions

1. The output shows "None" tokens, how do I know there is a token associated with this service account?
2. If I run `kubectl create token jenkins` command multiple times, will kubernetes create multiple tokens for this account? or the latest one will overwrite the previous one?

   ```
   # first time
   kubectl create token jenkins
   # second time
   kubectl create token jenkins
   # third time
   kubectl create token jenkins
   `
   ```
3. What's the mapping relation between the service account and the token? is it `1:n` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mechanism of service accounts and tokens has been changed (Moved to stable in v1.22).

In the past, you have created a service account. Then in the first time you ran a pod with that service account, Kubernetes created a long-lived, never expired, token that resided in secret of type `kubernetes.io/service-account-token`. Kubernetes attached this token to the pod via volume mount.

Due to the unsecured nature of long-lived tokens this has been changed to something called `Bound Service Account Token Volumes`.

In short, Kubernetes no more creates a secret with a token for the service account but instead Kubelet injects a short-lived token with a default timespan of 1 hour to the pod and refresh it when it's expired.

When you ran `kubectl describe serviceaccount jenkins` you saw `<none>` in the section of the `Tokens` because it represents the 'old fashioned' static tokens that as mentioned are not created by default anymore.

You can manually create such a static token with

```
> cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: jenkins
EOF
```

and then when you run `describe` again and you will the new token

```
> kubectl describe serviceaccount jenkins
Name:                jenkins
Namespace:           jenkins-demo
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              jenkins
Events:              <none>
```

You can create multiple tokens with different names and you will see all of them in the `describe` output.

**BUT** This is a bad practice to create these static tokens because they never expired. You should use short-lived token that you can create with the command you mentioned `kubectl create token jenkins`

You can control the duration with `--duration <seconds>s` and create a token with an expiration of up to 48h. The default is 1h.

The creation of new token doesn't overwrite the previous one. These tokens are JWTs - meaning they are signed and distributed, and are not kept on the server. If you want to see the content of a token you can paste the output
of `kubectl create token jenkins` in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

Same as with the static token. You can run
`kubectl get secret jenkins --output=jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 -d`
and paste the output in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). You can notice this token doesn't have an expiration date.

Reference:

1. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/
2. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-an-api-token-for-a-serviceaccount
3. https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-auth/1205-bound-service-account-tokens
4. https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/542